# ¿Cómo utilizar Python en el terminal de Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu

Quiero utilizar Python desde el terminal de Ubuntu, entonces he hecho un programa `testPostGreSQLPython.py`, pero me devolvía el siguiente error :

```
$ ./testPostGreSQLPython.py
bash: ./testPostGreSQLPython.py: /usr/bin/python2.4: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Aqui esta el programa :

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.4
#
# Small script to show PostgreSQL and Pyscopg together
#

import psycopg2

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='eclipse' user='swiper' host='eclipse.cganshho5qcf.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com' password=''")
except:
    print "I am unable to connect to the database"
```

He intentado determinar si existe la versión y el PATH de Python pero no lo he conseguido por el momento...

```
:~$ which python
/home/antoine/anaconda2/bin/python
:~$ which python2.4
$ echo $PATH
/home/antoine/anaconda2/bin:/home/antoine/bin:/home/antoine/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es por el "Shebang" del script, seguramente no existe python2.4 en la carpeta `/usr/bin`, por que pareciera que estás ejecutandolo desde un entorno virtual local. Te recomiendo que modifiques esto:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.4
```

por esto:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ! ¿Sabes porque me dice    `import psycopg2
ImportError: No module named psycopg2` ? Hay realmente un module que se llama psycopg2 y no le reconoce

Comment: Por lo que comentas estas corriendo python desde un entorno virtualizado de Anaconda, habría que revisar si en dicho entorno esta el paquete psycopg2 instalado correctamente, por ej: `pip freeze | grep psycopg2`